# How to Install Django on 2 version of python i.e on 2.7.9 and 3.4?

Tags: python, django

I already have installed django on 2.7.9 by using pip but when i was trying to install it in version 3.4 it give following message

```
C:\Python34>pip install django
 Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

Comment: use virtualenv or pyenv ... your paths are going to get really screwed up trying to do what you are doing

Comment: you should use virtualenv to separate out your installations.

Comment: that said I think you could do `c:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install django`

Comment: Thanks joran Beasley its worked. thanks once again